# Take $X$ from $ a = xTx^T $ (where a is a scalar)

Tags: linear-algebra

Good morning,

Can someone help me take the solution for this problem? In essense, $a$ is a scalar obtained by X (which is a $1\times n$ matrix), and $T$, which is a square matrix ($n\times n$), and we trying to obtain the value of $X$ knowing the values for $a$ and the matrix $T$.

$$ a = XTX^T  $$

Comment: I don't think you can without additional constraints. Take $T=I$. You are asking to recover $X$ from the knowledge of $a=\|X\|^2$. Geometrically you are asking to recover $X$ by only knowing that it lies on the sphere of radius $\sqrt{a}$. This is clearly underdetermined.

Comment: Trivial case: T is the identity matrix. Then $a=XX^T=|X|^2$ has a unique solution only for $a=0$. If $a<0$ there is no solution, if $a>0$ you have infinite solutions for $n>1$

Comment: Guess I'm screwed then.. thanks guys